# Macbook battery capacity lost 10% in 8 months, is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My 14 inch macbook with the m1 max chip has lost 10% of its battery capacity in 8 months of usage. Is this normal? I've also been using my iPhone pro max for about the same time and it only lost 1% of battery capacity.

Is this normal at all, or could this be because my macbook is always plugged in?

P.S. I do have the optimized battery charging turn on:
[image]

Here's the cycle count and the capacity:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s totally normal - especially if you use the machine a lot.

- https://www.apple.com/support/products/mac/

You can get battery service if it falls under 80% while in coverage like AppleCare. You’ve got the correct settings and as long as you keep it cool while charging you should be fine. The number can bounce so check on it again in 30 days.

Comment: Thanks! I guess 10% in almost a year is not that bad, means that in 5 years I'll lose 50%, and that will be half the capacity of the 17 hours promised by apple, which is 8,5 hours, which is still great?

Comment: I see these as very non linear, you might have a bad cell that drops 40% in a week or it might stay that way for three more years. Apple is now offering battery service for 10 years, so even with hundreds of macs, our budget for batteries is so low and always easy call based on how valuable that Mac is to us @pavel_orekhov

Comment: @pavel_orekhov I agree with bmike -  batteries often drop a lot within the first year, but then stabilize somewhat, then drop further towards end of life.