# Work from an outlet on MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I'm using a MacBook Pro 16-inch 2021 and noticed that the recharge cycle count is 34 after one and a half months of operation. I work at my desk most of the time and don't need autonomy.

If will I work from an outlet, will there be any negative impact on the battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MacBook is made with battery health and longevity features that you have to disable in software if you don’t want the maximum lifetime. That means you can plug and go.

As long as you don’t disable the battery health settings or break other guidelines for long term storage or high temperatures while charging you should expect excellent results.

- https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

The system will let you know if you don’t use the battery enough, but 1000+ discharge cycles is what we see on average for dozens upon dozens of machines that run like iMacs and are always plugged in at work.

I would add, set a 6 month reminder to [check stats and do a run down to empty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446130/5472) if you aren’t getting enough discharges to hit 1000 in 5 years (or 100 cycles every 6 months). Most people don’t need to do anything to be honest other than keep it cool / room temperature.